# Are there vines in nature that are naturally capable of being a whip, rope or string?

Tags: safety, ropes, trees, tree-climbing, jungle

Natural meaning, no human alteration to them besides chopping them off from a tree or any type of plant.

Ways I'm wondering if natural vines can be used.

- As a weapon, such as such as the bullwhip.
- As a rope for tying up objects.
- As a "jump rope" that can consistently hit the ground for a while without being damaged.

Traditional braided (human altered) vines won't solve the question, because I'm purely interested in whether there are any species of vines capable of being used for the above applications without editing their natural design.

I'm not knowledgable whatsoever about the vines of trees or any other plants. I've tried finding information online but I haven't personally had success finding information pertaining to the strength or flexibility of different vines.

Some characteristics I'm wondering if any species of vines have.

- How thick can a plants vine be.
- Are there only large vines with bark around them, or are there large vines (green) that are like a flowers "branches".

Comment: "string"-like, yes. But rope and string are normally braided.

Comment: There are a number of vines that can be used for cord or rope "as cut", but their strength will be unreliable. They are usually separated into fibres, which are twisted or/or braided into string and rope, for example sisal (string) and hemp (rope).

Comment: You can also use strips of bark from various trees as crude string. Although it's not the bark itself, but the inner layer. And "willow whips" are a quite versatile material.

Comment: Cross posted to Biology it seems: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/113394/are-there-vines-in-nature-that-are-naturally-capable-of-being-a-whip-rope-or-st

Comment: The world is a big place, please give more details on location or environment of the plants you are looking for. And do not cross post, make each question for each site different and adjusted to that site.

Comment: @Willeke I have no idea what specific plant or tree is capable of what I’m looking for, that’s why I asked the question without context and so broadly. And I couldn’t find anything else about the topic as I searched the internet. Also, then which stack exchange is proper for this. Somebody in the biology exchange said do world building instead.

Comment: If you are looking for some plant that might grow anywhere in the world or on a fictional planet, world building may work but do include why you are looking for such a plant. If you are looking for a plant available where you live (or travel) give that as detail and it might fit here.

Comment: The answer to the edited question is basically yes, there are vines that will meet at least one of your requirements, which is useless as an answer. Location is needed and more focus on what you need it for.

Comment: IMO the question is asked backwards. If you are in a particular place and need string or rope that you don't possess, *then* you would forage around to look for a suitable substitute. You can only use what is growing nearby, so it's useless going armed with loads of vine names that might do. Like when you buy a car: you only buy a specific car if there is one for sale.

Comment: Fascinating question!  The answer has to be yes.  Neolithic and Paleolithic people must have experimented with every naturally occurring thing, and used anything that was useful.     My guess is that the use of vines as crude cordage preceded homo sapiens, but that is only a guess.  And of course, no trace would have survived.   I have seen no mention in Jane Goodall's work of chimps using vines as cordage, so that gives an earlier limit in time (6 million years or so ago) for the use you ask about.   I may look into this further.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is yes, there are vines that do one or more of the things you want, and people in the (far) past have used them as such.

In the right time of the year brambles, the vines blackberries grow on, are harvested, thorns taken of, split in two or three and used to sew bee hives from straw. In the far past, before the splitting was usual the brambles were used as they came, they would be cleaned of thorns but other species of vines would grow without thorns. And that is just one example of use as a string I, grown up in the industrial part of the world, am familiar with.

If you look at the use of natural materials by peoples not from industrialised areas/times, you will see many uses of vines available where they live, which are often not known elsewhere or if known not used.

All vines have a core and bark structure as that is how plants grow, but the bark can be very thin and tender or quite hardy and/or rough, just as the vine as a plant need.

Vines can grow fast or slow. They can invest heavily in length and not grow thick, renewing the vines after the winter each year. Or they can grow thick at the base and keep on growing from there, a well known one for that is the grapevine, some old ones I have seen are as big as trees, over 30 cm/one foot, and as such would be suitable for a weapon.

I am not familiar with the vines of tropical regions, but I do know that there are many vines there that keep on growing and can reach enormous sizes, as there is no winter to kill them. So length and thickness are not limited.

Unless you specify a small part of the world, like a state in the US in size or even smaller, nobody can give you names of vines available and suitable, as there are just too many and most people have gone beyond using vines as found, as some simple processes, like braiding or twisting into rope does improve strength and reliability so much.

Comment: +1, also: An unstripped bramble is quite high on the list of things to avoid getting whipped with, along with wild rose stems of the right thickness.  They wouldn't be very effective for combat weapons or livestock management but for punishment whippings they'd work.  The normal cultivated grape vine, OTOH, are only flexible on  new growth, when they're quite weak. Old growth is basically just wood.  Either can be snapped too easily to tie knots in (I have a grape vine growing up my porch). ("English") Ivy  would be marginally better, leaves removed, but knotting will always be a problem

Answer (score 3):

This answer gives mostly only background to your question, but it is too interesting not to post, IMO.

From [Low Tech Magazine](https://solar.lowtechmagazine.com/2010/06/lost-knowledge-ropes-and-knots/):

> The earliest fossilized fragments of ropes and knots date back 15,000
> to 17,000 years, which makes the direct evidence of this technology
> much older than that of the axe (6000 BC) or the wheel (5000 BC).
> However, based on indirect evidence (perforated objects, wear marks on
> artefacts, bone needles, representations in art, etcetera),
> archaeologists believe that the use of ropes and knots dates between
> 250,000 and 2,500,000 years old.

This article further states:

> It is likely that the earliest “ropes” in prehistoric times were
> naturally occuring lengths of plant fiber, such as vines, followed by
> the first attempts at twisting and braiding these strands together to
> form the first proper rope in the modern sense of the word.

The article says that "modern apes have some very elementary skills at knotting and ropemaking [suggesting] that knot making may have preceded the genus homo."   (Quote may not be word-for-word exact, but the gist is correct.)

Moreover, if modern apes have these skills, the skills probably went back to the point where the lineage that eventually became chimpanzees  and the lineage that eventually became homo diverged, usually taken as about 6 million years ago. (!!)

As to WHAT vines, getting back to the actual question:  Strong vines are common in my area of northern Virginia, in fact, they have to be whacked back periodically (at least every few years) or they will start to overcome desirable plantings. There is something commonly called "grape vine" here, although I have never seen any grapes on it, which could be used to crudely tie branches together.  The main drawback of this mature vine is lack of flexibility, not strength, that is, it won't make a tight knot. THe vines grow to a great length, many feet.  Thus, strong vines are not a feature only of Tarzan-inhabited jungles, but do very well in temperate zones. The leaves die in the winter, but the vine is very, very hard to kill.  I know.